# failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

Can anyone help with this one? I am new to web developing and not sure what this error means?

> Warning: fopen(images/nophoto.png): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /home/u835626360/public_html/remove.html on line
>   101

can't this file/picture is open you need close

CODE:

```
$expire=time()-3600;
setcookie("dname","a", $expire);
setcookie("dpode","a", $expire);
}
function delpics($filename)
{
$path_to_file='userpics/';
$old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory
    chdir($path_to_file);
    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't this file/picture is open you need close ");
    fclose($fh);
    if (!unlink($filename))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted  $filename");
  }
    chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory   
}
```

Comment: it said, file not found

Comment: Can you at least post the full path to the image file ?

Comment: sorry what does this mean?

Comment: Please be aware that absolute file names (e.g., `/tmp/bla`) are still treated as relative(!) to `DocumentRoot` (at least in some environments).

Answer (score 12):

You need to give `fopen` the full path of the file, and you don't need `chdir()` at all. Try this version:

```
$path_to_file='userpics/';
$fh = fopen($path_to_file.$filename, 'w') or die('Permission error');
```

Comment: Hi whhere would i put this? What would i replace?

Comment: Delete `$old = getcwd();` and `chdir($path_to_file);`, and replace your exising `$fh = ` line, with the answer.

Comment: Thanks, i am still getting the error. the page now looks like this:
$expire=time()-3600;
setcookie("dname","a", $expire);
setcookie("dpode","a", $expire);
}
function delpics($filename)
{
$path_to_file='userpics/';
$fh = fopen($path_to_file.$filename, 'w') or die('Permission error');
    fclose($fh);
    if (!unlink($filename))
  {
  echo ("Error deleting $file");
  }
else
  {
  echo ("Deleted  $filename");
  }
    chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory

Comment: Everywhere you are using `$filename`, replace it with `$path_to_file.$filename` and remove `chdir($old)`. Make sure `$path_to_file` is the _full_ path, something like `/home/user/public_html/userpics/`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem. I was thinking file will be created if I use w or w+ but giving me above error.

So problem was we need to create dir before we can create file.

We can get absolute DIR path of file

```
$dir = dirname($filename);
```

Create DIR

```
//if(!is_dir($dir))
mkdir( $dir , 0755, true);
```

Third parameter is important you want recursively

I know it sound stupid but it may save someone's time so added here

Answer (score 1):

First make the dir manually in your server(if you have one) or local pc(if you dev in local)

Be sure to have write right for apache in your dir (0777 in unix-linux if you wan't to be sure you can do what you wan't and no idea for windows)

and then like it was said give the good path to fopen and not only filename

Comment: Please do not recommend `777` as permissions to any problem, **especially one that has to do with the web** - its an open door for exploits.

Comment: i have say if he wan't to be sure it's only for dev not for prod when you need to be sure what block you because some php conf don't allow acces to server dir or some path can be wrong, with 777 you are sure it's not os who block you and you can search another probleme then you can change to a 644 when it's work i don't say he need to keep 777 all time :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $expire=time()-3600;
    setcookie("dname","a", $expire);
    setcookie("dpode","a", $expire);

    function delpics($filename)
    {
    $path_to_file='/userpics/';
    $old = getcwd(); // Save the current directory
        chdir($old.$path_to_file);
        $fh = fopen($filename, 'w') or die("can't this file/picture is open you need close ");
        fclose($fh);
        if (!unlink($filename))
      {
      echo ("Error deleting $file");
      }
    else
      {
      echo ("Deleted  $filename");
      }
        chdir($old); // Restore the old working directory   
     }
```