# require failed to open stream: No such file or directory --Integrating Wordpress with current website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website [here](http://www.theoldhardwarestore.com).  I am trying to follow these instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) to integrate a Wordpress blog into the existing site.  I have installed Wordpress at /wordpress.  I then placed the following in the index.php for my blog page.

```
    <?php
require('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

But when I go to that page I get the error:

> require(/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory

If it makes any difference, the path to my index.php is:

> /themes/brooklyn-copy/views/custompage/index.php

Comment: `require()` needs a filesystem path, not the web path. The full error message will tell you what the filesystem path to your PHP file is, you should be able to tell which path to use from there.

Comment: Where is the error? Just check your files to see if that file is there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to open stream: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934912/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)